# Django: MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django, post, django-views, django-errors, django-request

I created this sign up form which is working perfectly fine. On the same template I created a login form. The sign up form has 3 parameters email, username and password while the login form has only username and password inputs. When I try to sign up everything works fine but when I try to login, it gives me
**MultiValueDictKeyError**

Here's my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.db import IntegrityError

# Create your views here.

def usersignup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'social_media/user.html')
    else:
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get['username'], password=request.POST.get['password'], email=request.POST['email'])
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'social_media/base.html')
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, 'social_media/user.html', {'error':'User already exists'})

def loginuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'social_media/user.html')
    else:
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST.get['username'], password=request.POST.get['password'])
        if user is none:
            return render(request, 'social_media/user.html', {'errorsignin':'Invalid User man'})
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'social_media/base.html')
```

Here's my HTML form:

```
{% load static %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
                
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Is there any way I can just take username and password for signing up the user and not email or do I have to add an email input field for signing in the user!

Regards

Vansh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
request.POST['']
```

with

```
request.POST.get('')
```

everywhere

example

```
request.POST['username']
```

to

```
request.POST.get('username')
```

Comment: yes it will remove MultiValueDictKeyError . try it out

Comment: Well that gives me a new error though: TypeError at /
'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: it's not because of that . can you please update your code in your question

Comment: yep I did that!

Comment: you are use [] instead of () . for ex .get['password']  should be .get('password')

Comment: I changed the brackets. Now the thing is my login form creates a new user :/ which is not supposed to happen ofc 

Comment: r u sure about my html names attribute though?

Comment: sorry i cant help with html what i know is to solve multivaluedict erroe

Comment: well I think HTML part is fine but do u know why it's creating a new user even on the login form?

Comment: your python code is correct mostly html is calling wrong function

Comment: well I'll take over that! Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

get is a method replace get[] with get() in views.py
rectify your form action in html